# Splitting one csv into multiple files

Tags: python, csv, split

I have a csv file of about 5000 rows in python i want to split it into five files.

I wrote a code for it but it is not working

```
import codecs
import csv
NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE = 1000
def again(count_file_header,count):
    f3 = open('write_'+count_file_header+'.csv', 'at')
    with open('import_1458922827.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        candidate_info_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        co = 0      
        for row in candidate_info_reader:
            co = co + 1
            count  = count + 1
            if count <= count:
                pass
            elif count >= NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE:
                count_file_header = count + NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE
                again(count_file_header,count)
            else:
                writer = csv.writer(f3,delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                writer.writerow(row)

def read_write():
    f3 = open('write_'+NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE+'.csv', 'at')
    with open('import_1458922827.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:


        candidate_info_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        count = 0       
        for row in candidate_info_reader:
            count  = count + 1
            if count >= NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE:
                count_file_header = count + NO_OF_LINES_PER_FILE
                again(count_file_header,count)
            else:
                writer = csv.writer(f3,delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                writer.writerow(row)

read_write()
```

The above code creates many fileswith empty content.

How to split one files into five csv files?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I suggest you not inventing a wheel. There is existing solution. Source [here](https://gist.github.com/jrivero/1085501)

```
import os


def split(filehandler, delimiter=',', row_limit=1000,
          output_name_template='output_%s.csv', output_path='.', keep_headers=True):
    import csv
    reader = csv.reader(filehandler, delimiter=delimiter)
    current_piece = 1
    current_out_path = os.path.join(
        output_path,
        output_name_template % current_piece
    )
    current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w'), delimiter=delimiter)
    current_limit = row_limit
    if keep_headers:
        headers = reader.next()
        current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i + 1 > current_limit:
            current_piece += 1
            current_limit = row_limit * current_piece
            current_out_path = os.path.join(
                output_path,
                output_name_template % current_piece
            )
            current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w'), delimiter=delimiter)
            if keep_headers:
                current_out_writer.writerow(headers)
        current_out_writer.writerow(row)
```

Use it like:

```
split(open('/your/pat/input.csv', 'r'));
```

Comment: if blank line between rows is an issue. just replace "w" with "wb" in file write object.

Comment: This code does not enclose column value in double quotes if the delimiter is "," comma. I have added option quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL  in csv.writer, however, it does not solve my issue.

Comment: @alexf I had the same error and fixed by modifying `headers = reader.next()` to `headers = next(reader)`

Comment: Adding to @Jim's comment, this is because of the differences between python 2 and python 3. Use the built-in function next in python 3. That is, write next(reader) instead of reader.next(). In addition, you should open the file in the text mode.

Answer (score 49):

**In Python**

Use `readlines()` and `writelines()` to do that, here is an example:

```
>>> csvfile = open('import_1458922827.csv', 'r').readlines()
>>> filename = 1
>>> for i in range(len(csvfile)):
...     if i % 1000 == 0:
...         open(str(filename) + '.csv', 'w+').writelines(csvfile[i:i+1000])
...         filename += 1
```

the output file names will be numbered `1.csv`, `2.csv`, ... etc.

**From terminal**

FYI, you can do this from the command line using `split` as follows:

```
$ split -l 1000 import_1458922827.csv
```

Comment: What will you do with file with length of 5003. Will you miss last 3 lines?

Comment: What do you do if the csv file is to large to hold in memory .

Comment: nice clean solution! thanks! and no, this solution does not miss any lines at the end of the file.

Comment: this is just missing repeating the csv headers in each file, otherwise it won't work as well later on

Comment: What if I want the same column index/name for all the CSV's as the original CSV. The subsets returned by the above code other than the '1.csv' does not have column names.

Comment: hi thanks! any idea how we can keep the header in each created csv file ?

Comment: Be aware, this code willn't work for strings with \n symbol inside string delimiter.

Comment: The code assumes you don't have multilines in the csv! this won't work for everything

Answer (score 7):

A python3-friendly solution:

```
def split_csv(source_filepath, dest_folder, split_file_prefix,
                records_per_file):
    """
    Split a source csv into multiple csvs of equal numbers of records,
    except the last file.

    Includes the initial header row in each split file.

    Split files follow a zero-index sequential naming convention like so:

        `{split_file_prefix}_0.csv`
    """
    if records_per_file <= 0:
        raise Exception('records_per_file must be > 0')

    with open(source_filepath, 'r') as source:
        reader = csv.reader(source)
        headers = next(reader)

        file_idx = 0
        records_exist = True

        while records_exist:

            i = 0
            target_filename = f'{split_file_prefix}_{file_idx}.csv'
            target_filepath = os.path.join(dest_folder, target_filename)

            with open(target_filepath, 'w') as target:
                writer = csv.writer(target)

                while i < records_per_file:
                    if i == 0:
                        writer.writerow(headers)

                    try:
                        writer.writerow(next(reader))
                        i += 1
                    except StopIteration:
                        records_exist = False
                        break

            if i == 0:
                # we only wrote the header, so delete that file
                os.remove(target_filepath)

            file_idx += 1
```

Comment: I threw this into an executable-friendly script. [Here it is](https://gist.github.com/traviswaelbro/fefc37b1ad36196e6b92cbb8cba8baa6) in case anybody else is trying to do the same as I was.

Answer (score 6):

A simple Python 3 solution with Pandas that doesn't cut off the last batch

```
def to_csv_batch(src_csv, dst_dir, size=30000, index=False):

    import pandas as pd
    import math
    
    # Read source csv
    df = pd.read_csv(src_csv)
    
    # Initial values
    low = 0
    high = size

    # Loop through batches
    for i in range(math.ceil(len(df) / size)):

        fname = dst_dir+'/Batch_' + str(i+1) + '.csv'
        df[low:high].to_csv(fname, index=index)
        
        # Update selection
        low = high
        if (high + size < len(df)):
            high = high + size
        else:
            high = len(df)
```

Usage example

```
to_csv_batch('Batch_All.csv', 'Batches')
```

Answer (score 5):

I have modified the accepted answer a little bit to make it simpler

**Edited**: Added the import statement, modified the print statement for printing the exception. @Alex F code snippet was written for python2, for python3 you also need to use `header_row = rows.__next__()` instead `header_row = rows.next()`. Thanks for pointing out.

```
import os
import csv
def split_csv_into_chunks(file_location, out_dir, file_size=2):
    count = 0
    current_piece = 1

    # file_to_split_name.csv
    file_name = file_location.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
    split_file_name_template = file_name + "__%s.csv"
    splited_files_path = []

    if not os.path.exists(out_dir):
        os.makedirs(out_dir)
    try:
        with open(file_location, "rb") as csv_file:
            rows = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
            headers_row = rows.next()
            for row in rows:
                if count % file_size == 0:
                    current_out_path = os.path.join(out_dir,
                                                    split_file_name_template%str(current_piece))
                    current_out_writer = None

                    current_out_writer = csv.writer(open(current_out_path, 'w'), delimiter=",")
                    current_out_writer.writerow(headers_row)
                    splited_files_path.append(current_out_path)
                    current_piece += 1

                current_out_writer.writerow(row)
                count += 1
        return True, splited_files_path
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception occurred as {}".format(e))
        return False, splited_files_path
```

Comment: print "Exception occurred as {}".format(e)
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 4):

Another pandas solution (each 1000 rows), similar to Aziz Alto solution:

```
suffix = 1
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        df[i:i+1000].to_csv(f"processed/{filename}_{suffix}.csv", sep ='|', index=False, index_label=False)
        suffix += 1
```

where `df` is the csv loaded as pandas.DataFrame; `filename` is the original filename, the pipe is a separator; `index` and `index_label` false is to skip the autoincremented index columns

Comment: Thanks this is the best and simplest solution I found for this challenge

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

@Ryan, Python3 code worked for me. I used `newline=''` as below to avoid the blank line issue:

```
with open(target_filepath, 'w', newline='') as target:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if count <= count:
   pass
```

This condition is always true so you pass everytime

Otherwise you can look at this post: [Splitting a CSV file into equal parts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947682/python-splitting-a-csv-file-into-equal-parts?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you leverage the possibilities offered by pandas. Here are functions you could use to do that :

```
def csv_count_rows(file):
    """
    Counts the number of rows in a file.
    :param file: path to the file.
    :return: number of lines in the designated file.
    """
    with open(file) as f:
        nb_lines = sum(1 for line in f)
    return nb_lines


def split_csv(file, sep=",", output_path=".", nrows=None, chunksize=None, low_memory=True, usecols=None):
    """
    Split a csv into several files.
    :param file: path to the original csv.
    :param sep: View pandas.read_csv doc.
    :param output_path: path in which to output the resulting parts of the splitting.
    :param nrows: Number of rows to split the original csv by, also view pandas.read_csv doc.
    :param chunksize: View pandas.read_csv doc.
    :param low_memory: View pandas.read_csv doc.
    :param usecols: View pandas.read_csv doc.
    """
    nb_of_rows = csv_count_rows(file)

    # Parsing file elements : Path, name, extension, etc...
    # file_path = "/".join(file.split("/")[0:-1])
    file_name = file.split("/")[-1]
    # file_ext = file_name.split(".")[-1]
    file_name_trunk = file_name.split(".")[0]
    split_files_name_trunk = file_name_trunk + "_part_"

    # Number of chunks to partition the original file into
    nb_of_chunks = math.ceil(nb_of_rows / nrows)
    if nrows:
        log_debug_process_start = f"The file '{file_name}' contains {nb_of_rows} ROWS. " \
            f"\nIt will be split into {nb_of_chunks} chunks of a max number of rows : {nrows}." \
            f"\nThe resulting files will be output in '{output_path}' as '{split_files_name_trunk}0 to {nb_of_chunks - 1}'"
        logging.debug(log_debug_process_start)

    for i in range(nb_of_chunks):
        # Number of rows to skip is determined by (the number of the chunk being processed) multiplied by (the nrows parameter).
        rows_to_skip = range(1, i * nrows) if i else None
        output_file = f"{output_path}/{split_files_name_trunk}{i}.csv"

        log_debug_chunk_processing = f"Processing chunk {i} of the file '{file_name}'"
        logging.debug(log_debug_chunk_processing)

        # Fetching the original csv file and handling it with skiprows and nrows to process its data
        df_chunk = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=file, sep=sep, nrows=nrows, skiprows=rows_to_skip,
                               chunksize=chunksize, low_memory=low_memory, usecols=usecols)
        df_chunk.to_csv(path_or_buf=output_file, sep=sep)

        log_info_file_output = f"Chunk {i} of file '{file_name}' created in '{output_file}'"
        logging.info(log_info_file_output)
```

And then in your main or jupyter notebook you put :

```
# This is how you initiate logging in the most basic way.
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
file = {#Path to your file}
split_csv(file,sep=";" ,output_path={#Path where you'd like to output it},nrows = 4000000, low_memory = False)
```

P.S.1 : I put `nrows = 4000000` because when it's a personal preference. You can change that number if you wish.

P.S.2 : I used the logging library to display messages. When would apply such a function on big files that exist on a remote server, you really want to avoid 'simple printing' and incorporate logging capabilities. You can replace `logging.info` or `logging.debug` with `print`

P.S.3 : Of course, you need to replace the `{# Blablabla}` parts of the code with your own parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler script works for me.

```
import pandas as pd
path = "path to file" # path to file
df = pd.read_csv(path) # reading file

low = 0 # Initial Lower Limit
high = 1000 # Initial Higher Limit
while(high < len(df)):
    df_new = df[low:high] # subsetting DataFrame based on index
    low = high #changing lower limit
    high = high + 1000 # givig uper limit with increment of 1000
    df_new.to_csv("Path to output file") # output file
```

Answer (score 1):

Building upon the top voted answer, here is a python solution that also includes the headers in each file.

```
file = open('file.csv', 'r')
header = file.readline()
csvfile = file.readlines()
filename = 1
batch_size = 1000
for i in range(len(csvfile)):
        if i % batch_size == 0:
                open(str(filename) + '.csv', 'w+').writelines(header)
                open(str(filename) + '.csv', 'a+').writelines(csvfile[i:i+batch_size])
                filename += 1
```

This will output the same file names as 1.csv, 2.csv, ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

file_len = len(df)
filename = 'output'
n = 1
for i in range(file_len):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        sf = (df[i:i+10])
        sf.to_csv(f'{filename}_{n}.csv', index=False)
        n += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a very simple solution, that does not loop over all rows, but only on the chunks - imagine if you have millions of rows.

```
chunk_size = 100_000
for i in range(len(df) // chunk_size + 1):
    df[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size].to_csv(f"output_{i:02d}.csv", 
                                             sep=";", index=False)
```

You define the chunk size and if the total number of rows is not an integer multiple of the chunk size, the last chunk will contain the rest.

Using `f"output_{i:02d}.csv"` the suffix will be formatted with two digits and a leading zero

If you want to have a header only for the first chunk (and no header for the other chunks), then you can use a boolean over the suffix index at `i == 0`, that is:

```
for i in range(len(df) // chunk_size + 1):
    df[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size].to_csv(f"output_{i:02d}.csv", 
                                             sep=";", index=False, header=(i == 0))
```