# Split CSV files with headers in windows using python and remove text qualifiers from line start and end

Tags: python, csv

I have a large csv file for which i need to split the file. I have
 managed to split the file using the below python code:

```
 import csv

 divisor = 500000

 outfileno = 1 outfile = None

 with open('file_temp.txt', 'r') as infile:
     for index, row in enumerate(csv.reader(infile)):
         if index % divisor == 0:
             if outfile is not None:
                 outfile.close()
             outfilename = 'big-{}.csv'.format(outfileno)
             outfile = open(outfilename, 'w')
             outfileno += 1
             writer = csv.writer(outfile)
         writer.writerow(row)
```

The problem i'm facing is that the file header is not getting copied
 to the rest of the files. Can you please let me know how can i modify
 my code to add the headers in the different splitted files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonically add header to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347766/pythonically-add-header-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [splitting one csv into multiple files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445193/splitting-one-csv-into-multiple-files-in-python)

Comment: those did not solve my issue as i could not understand how to run them as i am new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to cache the header row and then write it out for each CSV file, something like:

```
import csv

divisor = 500000
outfileno = 1
outfile = None

try:
    with open('file_temp.txt', 'r') as infile:
        infile_iter = csv.reader(infile)
        header = next(infile_iter)
        for index, row in enumerate(infile_iter):
            if index % divisor == 0:
                if outfile is not None:
                    outfile.close()
                outfilename = 'big-{}.csv'.format(outfileno)
                outfile = open(outfilename, 'w')
                outfileno += 1
                writer = csv.writer(outfile)
                writer.writerow(header)
            writer.writerow(row)
finally:
    # Don't forget to close the last file
    if outfile is not None:
        outfile.close()
```

Since you're only working with lines, you don't really need to use the CSV module, here's a version that works without it:

```
divisor = 500000
outfileno = 1
outfile = None

try:
    with open('file_temp.txt', 'r') as infile:
        header = next(infile)
        for index, row in enumerate(infile):
            if index % divisor == 0:
                if outfile is not None:
                    outfile.close()
                outfilename = 'big-{}.csv'.format(outfileno)
                outfile = open(outfilename, 'w')
                outfileno += 1
                outfile.write(header)
            outfile.write(row)
finally:
    # Don't forget to close the last file
    if outfile is not None:
        outfile.close()
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the quick response. I noticed that when i am running the code above, the first file is getting a double quote at the start of each line and at the end of each line. This is not happening for the rest of the splitted files. Please help. Example "abc,asd,dsf,sdg,sgd"

Comment: Hmm, that isn't happening for me at all. Since you only care about preserving copying individual lines you could simplify things and remove all the CSV logic. I will post an updated example.