# How to handle large files with s3fs?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am working on AWS EMR Cluster. I have a data on my S3 storage. After I clean my data, i am sending to my S3 storage again via s3fs library. The code works with files which size are between 200-500 mb. However, when i am uploading between 2.0 and 2.5 gb size. The code gives a error which is "MemoryError". Do you guys any ideas or expericence about this issue?

```
import s3fs
bytes_to_write = nyc_green_20161.to_csv(None).encode()
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(key='#', secret='#')
with fs.open('s3://ludditiesnyctaxi/new/2016/yellow/yellow_1.csv', 'wb') as f:
f.write(bytes_to_write)
```

Comment: You'll probably need to chunk or stream these operations.

Comment: hi, could you give an example about chunk? how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handle this problem to split my csv files. This post explains how to split csv files [splitting one csv into multiple files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445193/splitting-one-csv-into-multiple-files-in-python/36445821)